# Turn (15) degrees scratch block doesn't work

Tags: mit-scratch

When ran, the **the turn (15) degrees block** doesn't  work- for example:

`When gf clicked
say [Waaah!]
turn (15) degrees`


When gf clicked
say [Waaah!]
turn (15) degrees

The sprite would say Waaah!, but wouldn't turn.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there aren't any other scripts in your sprite which would keep it from turning (e.g. a forever loop that makes it point in a particular direction), a likely cause of this is having previously used the "set rotation style" motion block. This block changes the visual behavior of how a sprite faces based on its direction value. (That's jargon for "it changes the way a sprite looks, but not how the move-steps and if-on-edge-bounce blocks behave.")

Typically, you'll want your sprites to have the "all around" rotation style (this is the default value). Your sprite may be of the style "left-right" or "don't rotate"; both these options limit the way the sprite will face. (The former, it'll face closest to +90 or -90 degrees; the latter, it'll always face 90 degrees.) You can get your sprite back to normal by using the "set rotation style" block with the input "all around".

Answer (score 1):

The `Say Waaaaah!` block means it will be executed forever and will not execute the next code until it is executed. Since the say block is executed forever, it will not execute the block `Turn (15) degrees`. You may want to put them into two seperate codes:

```
When Green Flag clicked
forever turn (15) degrees

When Green Flag clicked
say Waaaaah!
```

Comment: The say block isn't executed forever. It just shows the speech bubble but doesn't hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because of the "say [Waaah!]" block isn't set for a specific time. Replace the "say [Waaah!]" block with a "say [Waaah!] for [2] secs" block. See if that works. :D

Comment: The say block isn't executed forever. It just shows the speech bubble but doesn't hide it.